# Perl: How to convert big endian to little endian

Tags: perl, endianness

This problem is solved. Thank you so much guys^^

My problem and the solution I am using is stated below.

Original problem: --- Edited 2013-05-08

I know that I can do this task by C++ like this:

```
struct {              /* File Header */
    int a;
    int b;
    short c;    
    short d;
} PPPhdr;
PPPhdr head;
fstream fst;
fst.open("file.txt", ios_base::in|ios_base::binary);
fst.read((char*)&head, sizeof(PPPhdr));
SwapInt32(&(head.a));
SwapInt32(&(head.b));
SwapShort(&(head.c));
SwapShort(&(head.d));
```

So, basically SwapInt32 will do this:

```
0x89346512 -> 0x12653489
```

SwapShort will do this:

```
0x3487 -> 0x8734
```

Now my question is, how can I do this in Perl?

My way:

```
open FH, "<file.txt" or die print "Cannot open file\n";
binmode FH;
read FH, $temp, 12;
($a,$b) = unpack("N2", substr($temp,0,8));
($c,$d) = unpack("n2", substr($temp,8,4));
close(FH);
print "$a\n$b\n$c\n$d\n";
```

Comment: Can you show what the input is and what the expected output is in hex?

Comment: 0x89346512 -> 0x12653489 ---This is what I want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say your data is big-endian, but you are using the `i` template (a signed integer value) in the unpack call.  You should be using `N` (an unsigned 32-bit big-endian number).  You may want to read the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).

Comment: Thank you I have tried this:
`$temp = unpack("N", $temp);`
`print $temp;`
this result is same as:
`$temp = unpack("i>", $temp);`
`print $temp;`
And this is not what I want.

Comment: One follow up question. How to convert a signed 32-bit big-endian number?

Comment: Due to the way integers wrap, this should work: `$temp -= 2**32 if $temp > (2**31-1)`

Answer (score 2):

Perl doesn't have a single-character format for a signed big-endian integer.  Use `pack 'i>'` for that. (This requires at least Perl 5.10.)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this:  <br>`$temp = unpack("i>", $temp);`
<br> `print $temp;`
<br> but the answer is not what I want.
<br> what should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pack it and unpack the other way round:

```
print "ok\n" if 0x12653489 == unpack 'L', pack 'N', 0x89346512;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this.  First I sensed whether I am bigendian or littleendian.  Either read the file and look at the endian flag (bytes 0-1 in a TIFF file for instance), or sense my own system's endianness by

```
  $x = pack ("S", 256); 
  $bigendian = ord(substr ($x, 0, 1));    # 1 for bigendian 0 for littleendian
```

Once I have a value for $bigendian, I use variables for packing and unpacking:

```
  $short = $bigendian ? "n" : "v"; 
  $long = $bigendian ? "N" : "V"; 
  ($a,$b) = unpack($long . "2", substr($temp,0,8));
  ($c,$d) = unpack($short . "2", substr($temp,8,4));
```

nN stands for "network" which is a standard that calls for bigendian

vV stands for "Vax", an old DEC system  which is littleendian